# Problem with Foreman --- > engine.rb:201:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, foreman

I am trying to start a ruby on rails server along with React JS; in my procfile.dev I have the following:

```
web: rails server -p 3000
js: yarn build --watch
```

But when I try to run foreman I get this error :

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile.dev
13:03:37 web.1  | started with pid 21400
13:03:37 js.1   | started with pid 9904
13:03:37 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.19
13:03:37 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --watch
13:03:37 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
13:03:37 js.1   | Done in 0.39s.
13:03:38 js.1   | exited with code 0
13:03:38 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:201:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:201:in `kill_children'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:473:in `terminate_gracefully'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:439:in `wait_for_shutdown_or_child_termination'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:60:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/cli.rb:42:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `<main>'
```

I already tried to fixed the problem looking at the manifest file and the procfile.dev but I couldnt.

Comment: What happens when you start rails server separately?

Comment: To add to Konstantin's question:
What happens when you manually run either of the Procfile commands?
ie `rails s`
and `yarn build --watch`

Comment: It seems that the issue is with the yarn command in the procfile.dev. Try changing the js entry in the procfile to use the yarn start command instead of yarn build --watch. It should look like this:

js: yarn start

Comment: I can perfectly start the project separately, if I run rails s, the rails server goes live perfectly, and if I run yarn build --watch it also works at perfection. The problem its that I cannot start both servers with the procfile.dev or the bin/dev command.